Kitchen GFCI near sink on 2 circuits
New homeowner, so I didn’t do any of this work. House was recently remodeled.
I have an odd wiring configuration on the GFCI outlet in the kitchen that tripped under load and broke the last GFCI outlet.
2 hot wires (1 black on 20 amp, 1 white now labeled with 2 black stripes is hot on both the 20 amp circuit and a 15 amp circuit)
They are in phase so only 120v even from both hots with both circuits on. They do not combine for 240v.
The other black is common to the 20 amp
The other white is neutral.
The refrigerator is on the 20 amp line along with a GFCI and second outlet.
4 LED lights overhead lights on the 15 amp breaker.
So obviously this is not a double pole breaker. They are on opposite sides of breaker box.
When the first GFCI blew, wife had toaster oven and air fryer running on the GFCI outlet, which was also running lights and fridge.  No breaker tripped since the loads are split across the separate 15 and 20 amp breakers. But both other outlets were dead and the lights were still on. This meant no fridge!
They are wired with both blacks on one side of “load” terminal and both whites on opposite side of “load” terminal. And all grounded.
I know this means all other connections are then protected under GFCI except the lights.
When the gfci blew, the lights stayed on bc that circuit is still connected with hot and common on the same screw.
The really messed up part is the whole house was recently remodeled and gutted entire first floor. All the LED lights were added. A bunch of outlets on second floor were terminated bc they took out the floor to make a grand entrance, so they should have had more breakers available rather than daisy chain the fridge to the gfci with branch from lights, even with only 100 amp service. I guess my question is why? And it appears I cannot separate the circuits with GFCI outlet, can I at least keep the fridge running so it’s not on GFCI?
I’m not very experienced with electric, but have installed breakers, outlets, and switches, but not all together in daisy or multi circuit.
Does this mean somewhere there is a black and white crossed or shorted between 2 circuits? Or did they intentionally add the second circuit so they wouldn’t blow the breaker with the load of the fridge and other kitchen appliances running at same time? They underestimated my wife’s cooking if so.
Side note they might be related, there is a hood above the stove that is wired, but doesn’t turn on. Possible related.


Confirm you have a hot white and a neutral white on the same screw/side of the GFCI receptacle.   Hot and neutral connected is a dead short and should trip any breaker as soon as it is turned on.

I already put it back together, but definitely hot white, which is hot on both the 15 amp (lights) and 20 amp (fridge+gfci+2nd outlet) breaker. The white neutral is for the 20 amp breaker. I think it doesn’t trip the breaker bc it’s split to 2 circuit breakers. When the gfci failed, the fridge and kitchen outlets were off, but the lights stayed on.

Can you add some photos of the actual connections.  And it would be very helpful if you could make a sketch that shows the wiring as completely as you've been able to figure out.  It's very difficult to imagine what's going on based on the descriptions.  Also, what is "black common".

Also, the wiring shown in your sketch would trip the breakers as crip659 noted, and that includes both the 15 and 20 amp breakers if wired as you describe.

You write "both blacks on one side of “load” terminal and both whites on opposite side of “load” terminal", but what's on the line terminals of the GFCI? You have to have incoming power connected to line for the GFCI to work and be able to protect downstream outlets on its load terminals.

Gentlemen. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. You were correct, and I am confused. I disassembled wiring from the gfci outlet with both 15 and 20 amp breakers off. With just the 15 on, I confirmed there are no hot wires. With just the 20 on, I confirmed there is 1 hot black wire. Which means I turned the wrong 20 amp breaker off yesterday, and that’s why I got shocked… I removed the black striping from the white wire and reassembled with both blacks on the “line” side and both whites on the opposite “line” side. That’s also where they were originally (writing is upside down on back)

I got myself one of those handy Klein tools plug checker for safety if I ever open an outlet again.

Also, in my defense, we just moved here last week. The dishwasher is not hooked to power, and the vent hood is hooked to power, but doesn’t turn on. I thought they did some dumb things with electric, but I guess they were trying to make do with 100 amp service. I would have started there with the remodel before dumping money into the rest.  I’m planning an upgrade to 200 and will hire a certified electrician of course. Thanks again!
